# Wakanda remove element sources

Tags: wakanda

I would like to remove one row of the dataGrid.
I try :

```
sources.myData.getCurrentElement().remove();
```

but i have one error : INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500.

Someone can explain me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [removeCurrent()](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Datasource/Local-Datasources/removeCurrent.301-624341.en.html).

You can also use the **-**  button at the bottom of the Grid.
it allows you to delete the currently selected datastore entity.This button can be hidden if you select the Read only property for the Grid.